# When is compute_final_grade($responses, $totaltries) called?

Tags: moodle

I'm trying to understand how question types work in moodle, almost all of them implement ***compute_final_grade($responses, $totaltries)*** , but i couldn't find when this method is called?
i debugged an example question in a quiz and submitted, after submit moodle only calls ***grade_response(array $response)*** method and grades the answer but i didn't find the source that calls this method or where this method is used.

Comment: Is it something that's only necessary for certain question behaviours?

Comment: Yes i guess so, questions like match and gapselect implemmented it.

Comment: It certainly sounds like it's only relevant when there are multiple tries and the system has to do something to work out an aggregated score.  If you're doing a single attempt or highest score then it's probably not called.